# jquery - get value from multiple dropdowns with same id

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have these dynamic dropdowns with dynamic ids and value.

```
<select id=extra['123']></select>
<select id=extra['453']></select>
<select id=extra['789']></select>
```

In php, I am able to get the value using:

```
$_REQUEST['extra']
```

And I get an array.

```
[extra] => Array
    (
        [123] => 0
        [453] => 0
        [789] => 0
    )
```

But how do I create an array in jquery? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wild card

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp64H/)**

```
selectArray = $('[id^=extra]');
```

Iterating throuh all selects

```
selectArray.each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
})​
```

For getting the numbers in id of selects

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp64H/1/)**

```
selectArray = $('[id^=extra]');
ids = selectArray.map(function() {
    return this.id.replace("extra['", "").replace("']", "");
}).get().join();
alert(ids);
​
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can create a string further like 123,453,789. And alert the this string?

Comment: selectArray.join() to get 123,453,789

Comment: okay this is going great. but i am getting ids only. how can i get id along with the value.for eg:

Comment: selectArray is array objects so id need to be extracted.

Comment: 123:value,453:value,789:value

Comment: this worked fine. the only problem now is its alerting all fields having id starting with extra. for eg: extra_price, extra_local. I only want id:value from the fields with id extra['id']. did you understand?

Comment: Change select to  $('select[id^=extra]') if it helps, http://jsfiddle.net/Qp64H/4/